# MySQL - Select Club Name and list all members in one query?

Tags: mysql

1. I have a "clubs" table and a "members" table
2. I'd like a query to return the club name (clubs.name) and each member's nickname (members.nickname)

I can get them all using an inner join,

```
SELECT clubs.name AS `Club Name`, members.nickname AS `Member Handle`
FROM clubs
INNER JOIN members ON clubs.club_id = members.club_id
```

but that shows the club.name field for each member.nickname.

```
| Club Name   | Member Handle |
-------------------------------   
| Club Yellow | Jim-Bob       |
| Club Yellow | Clem          | 
| Club Yellow | Mustache Pete |
| Club Green  | Ladyhawke     |
| Club Green  | Rosie         |
```

Is it at all possible to receive result like so?

```
| Club Name   | Member Handle |
-------------------------------   
| Club Yellow | Jim-Bob       |
|             | Clem          | 
|             | Mustache Pete |
| Club Green  | Ladyhawke     |
|             | Rosie         |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No in mysql you can not generate the result like this, you need to use application level to do it. However you can format the data i.e. all the `member-handle` as comma-separated values

```
SELECT 
clubs.name AS `Club Name`,
group_concat(members.nickname) AS `Member Handle`
FROM clubs
INNER JOIN members ON clubs.club_id = members.club_id 
group by clubs.name
```

Comment: Yeah i figured as much, but it never hurts to ask :) group_concat is nice as I can then do an explode()  on the commas in php.